# Easiest way to pass a javascript array or its values to a servlet using jQuery's ajax() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, servlets

I have a Javascript array. I want to pass it's data to a servlet using the ajax() method of jQuery.

What is the easiest way to do this. The index values i.e. the i in array[i] are not in order, they are numbers that have meaning themselves, hence I cannot simply loop through and create a GET queryString, or so I believe.

Maybe I should be converting the JavaScript array to a JSON Object and sending that to the server ??

I am stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$.post('your page', {data : yourjavascriptarray}, function() {

});
```